# How to share a ManagedObjectContext when using UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, uitabbarcontroller, cocoa-design-patterns

I have an iPhone application that has a MainWindow.xib holding a UITabBarController, which in turn has a UINavigationController and a custom UIViewController subclass in its ViewControllers array. The root view controller for the UINavigationController and the custom view controller are both loaded from other xib files.

The app uses core data, the stack is initialized in the app delegate (as per [the convention](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008283-SW2)).

The app delegate adds the UITabBarController to the window:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {        
    // Configure and show the window
    [window addSubview:[tabBarController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

I realize that I need to propagate a pointer to the ManagedObjectContext created in the app delegate, but I don't know how to proceed (even reading all the good commentary on the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908201/confused-in-getting-the-managedobjectcontext-from-appdelegate) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267520/where-to-place-the-core-data-stack-in-a-cocoa-cocoa-touch-application)):

- Do I propagate the ManagedObjectContext to the UITabBarController and from there on to the individual view controllers and if so, how?
- Or do I propagate the ManagedObjectContext directly to the root view controller of the UINavigationController and to the custom view controller and how would I do that?

I guess I don't understand well enough how to work with the UITabBarController.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ideally you want to pass either the `NSManagedObjectContext`, `NSFetchedResultsController` or the relevant `NSManagedObject` "down" into the `UIViewController`.  This allows the "parent" to control the "child" and determine what the child should have.  This creates a more loosely coupled design and allows you to easily re-arrange `UIViewController` instances as needed.  It also makes it easier to reuse a `UIViewController`.

In a tab view design it is no different.  Your AppDelegate passes the `NSManagedObjectContext` to whoever is responsible for creating the initial `UIViewController` instances that go into the `UITabBarController`.  In turn that creator passes the relevant information (`NSManagedObject`, `NSFetchedResultsController`, and/or `NSManagedObject` instances) into the `UIViewController` instances as it is constructing them.

Comment: Yes, they took down the articles, I will repost it on CIMGF soon.

Comment: Would be helpful to post simple answer for tabbar, instead of a link.  Links go stale.

Comment: The answer I posted is complete on its own without the link.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use the dependency injection method to pass the managed object context with a tab bar controller, a more robust solution would be to loop on all the view controllers in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

```
for (id vc in tabBarController.viewControllers) {
    [vc setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good, I looked long and hard at the CoreDataBooks sample application and did it like this:

- Created IBOutlets to the RootViewController (the top view controller of the UINavigationController) and the MapViewController (the custom view controller) in the app delegate.
- Connected the outlets to the view controllers in the MainWindow.xib
- Added the following code to `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

  ```
  // pass the managed object context to the view controllers
  RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[navigationController topViewController];
  rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

  mapViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
  ```

And now it works like a charm.

Comment: Can you explain in details what did you do, please.

Comment: today it's all clear, actually i don't remember what i missed at that moment and why couldn't understand it, anyway thx for reply :)

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this same problem, i'll share my solution.

First you need a reference to the Nav Controller in the Tab Bar in the nib file, make sure you connect it up.

```
IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Then, get the Controller as recommended in the support docs and send it the managedObjectContext:

```
SavedTableViewController *saved = (SavedTableViewController *)[navigationController topViewController];
saved.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Alex (from another post) is right, "You should generally stay away from getting shared objects from the app delegate. It makes it behave too much like a global variable, and that has a whole mess of problems associated with it."

Answer (score 0):

Using Xcode 3.2.1 and targeting 3.1.3 I've had endless problems with the

```
rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

approach that mvexcel describes (and that it is used all throughout the sample apps), however using exactly the same approach but phrasing it as:

```
[rootViewController setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

works perfectly.

I've also had a lot of problems with interface builder not synching correctly with Xcode and so not being able to connect up the outlets to pass the context through. Hopefully the next release fixes all this.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I know this is an old thread, but I'm also having problems finding the best way to handle sharing a MOC between TABS - wish Marcus Zarra's link on the subject was still active. Marcus totally rocks, makes data cool.

This is my current solution in application didFinishLaunching:

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [tabBarController viewControllers];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    for (id viewController in viewControllers) {
        [viewController setManagedObjectContext:context];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a rootViewController and then I have a TabBarController, so in the segue when I prepare the tabBarController I set its delegate:

`if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"initialTabBar"]) 
     [(UITabBarController *)[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];`
}`

I add the protocol to the tabBarDelegate in my RootViewController (I called MainViewController):

`@interface MainViewController ()<UITabBarControllerDelegate>`

And finally in the delegate method:

`-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{`

I set the property, but previously I make sure that viewcontroller has the correct property:

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

    if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(managedContextObject)]) {
    [viewController setValue:self.managedObjectContext forKey:@"managedContextObject"];
    }
}
```

Thus, if any of the viewController´s tab don´t use the managedContextObject simply I don´t create the property in its .h

I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through each viewController, check if it has a `managedObjectContext` property and then set it if so. This is the cleanest way I could find to do it.

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
for (id viewController in [tabBarController viewControllers]) {
    if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setManagedObjectContext:)]) {
        [viewController setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A more straight-forward solution is to make the ManagedObjectContext your app delegate's public property so wherever you need access to it you would do the following:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sharedManagedObjectContext];
```

assuming that *sharedManagedObjectContext* is the property name.

Comment: That might work, and I'll try it, but I'm still curious how to do it following the design pattern Apple lays out in its documentation (see the link in my question). Thanks for the answer in any case.

Comment: That really depends on your app's architecture. You don't have to setup the NSManagedObjectContext in your app delegate, especially if your use of it is restricted to one view controller, in which case you set it up in that view controller. If I can read it right, Apple suggests you initialize your view controllers passing the shared NSManagedObjectContext using a custom -initWithManagedObjectContext: method (you write something like this yourself), but this approach won't easily work for a complex view hierarchy.

Comment: No, do *not* do this. No Apple example follows this pattern; it's not recommended (see http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008283-SW1). You should pass a context or a managed object from one view controller to the next.