# Core Data and UITabBar Controller - help?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data, uitabbarcontroller

So I have a Project with a UITabBarController and a few Navigation Controllers, and I am trying to implement Core Data. Its just not working.

I have a bit of a weird setup:
UITabBarController -> Navigation Controller -> Table View Controller

I have copied all of the Core Data code and added an entity with an attribute ('Event' and 'name' - just like the tutorials). I keep getting the error:
erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Event''

The error only occurs when I switch to the Table View I want populated by the Core Data content.

I found that the error occurs on this line in the Table View Controller:

`NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];`

This seems to correspond with this (in the App Delegate):

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

if (!context) {

    // Handle the error.
```

NSLog(@"\nCould not create *context for self");

```
}

rootViewController.managedObjectContext = context;
```

Any Help?

**Update:** I managed to get it working (very exciting moment, and Stanford is winning at the half - so far its a good day). I am now referencing it from the App Delegate. Ahhh, this feels soo good :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your managed object context is probably not set and the entity "Event" is obviously not valid for a nil context.

I use a reference to my app delegate in all my view controllers so they can access the one managed object context. It sounds like others often use a singleton to manage Core Data and would get the managed object context from that.

**UPDATE**

There is a good discussion about where to keep the Core Data stack in [Where to place the “Core Data Stack” in a Cocoa/Cocoa Touch application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267520/where-to-place-the-core-data-stack-in-a-cocoa-cocoa-touch-application).

Here is some example code for keeping the Core Data stack in the app delegate:

Use Apple's standard Core Data stack implementation in YourAppDelegate. managedObjectContext is implemented as an example, but managedObjectModel and persistentStoreCoordinator must be implemented as well.

**YourAppDelegate.h**:

```
@interface YourAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    // Core Data stuff
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;       
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

    // other app ivars
}
```

**YourAppDelegate.m**:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return managedObjectContext;
    }
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }
    return managedObjectContext;
}
```

In every view controller, get a reference to the app delegate and use it to get the managedObjectContext as needed. For example, when setting up the fetchedResultsController;

**RootViewController.h**:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

    YourAppDelegate *app;
}
```

**RootViewController.m**:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "YourAppDelegate.h"

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize fetchedResultsController;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    app = (YourAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:app.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // setup the batch size, predicate, & sort keys, etc

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:app.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: can you give me an example of how you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your TableView (rootViewController) in IB hooked up to the outlet in your app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this same problem, i'll share my solution.

First you need a reference to the Nav Controller in the Tab Bar in the nib file, make sure you connect it up.

```
IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Then, get the Controller as recommended in the support docs and send it the managedObjectContext:

```
SavedTableViewController *saved = (SavedTableViewController *)[navigationController topViewController];
saved.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Alex (from another post) is right, "You should generally stay away from getting shared objects from the app delegate. It makes it behave too much like a global variable, and that has a whole mess of problems associated with it."

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the exact same issue and described how to fix it here:

[iPhone: core data error: +entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993977/iphone-core-data-error-entityforname-could-not-locate-an-nsmanagedobjectmodel/7605347#7605347)

You need to add this line to your app delegate where you create the view controllers for the tab bar:

```
yourViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting gerry3:

> It sounds like others often use a singleton to manage Core Data and would get the managed object context from that.

For anyone trying to solve this problem by implementing it using a singleton, I started new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107390/entityforname-could-not-locate-an-nsmanagedobjectmodel-for-entity-name-when-us).