# iOS Add a row to UITableView on button click from another ViewController

Tags: ios, tableview

I am a new in iOS Development and I can´t move forwards...  Is here somebody with experience, who can help me to solve my problem?

I use a Storyboard. First you see a ViewController with buttons. When you click on one of the button, informations about this button appear in a TableViewCell. - until now is it clear.

Than you click on a button "Continue" (than you come back to ViewController with buttons) and choose another button from ViewController.

HOW to do it, **that informations from this button comes to a TableView as a second Cell**? (so that when you click on for example three of the buttons, they appear as 3 cells under each other in this table?)

[My Sample Code is here to download.](http://www.file-upload.net/download-6913604/TestTableView.zip.html) - (on this website click on the smallest icon "Download").

Thank you very very much for your help!!!

Iva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `Model` to store your selections/data.

For example: On `MainViewController`, when you click on `button1`, record that in the `Model` using array or just variable. Then, when you load `SecondViewController`, check the values in Model and load cells accordingly.

=> Example code for Model

```
// Header
@interface ModelData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray selectedProducts;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger value1;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger value2;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger value3;

@end


// Implementation
@implementation ModelData

@synthesize selectedProducts = _selectedProducts;
@synthesize value1 = _value1;
@synthesize value2 = _value2;
@synthesize value3 = _value3;

@end
```

---

Various options:

1. Use `NSUserDefaults` to store information like settings
2. Use a `Model` class as described above - it could be a singleton class
3. Use `CoreData` to store and retrieve your data - complicated approach and suitable for dynamic things

---

Here is a reference to a good [Data Model tutorial](http://www.hollance.com/2011/04/making-your-classes-talk-to-each-other-part-1/) (reported by Iva)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Your answer is for sure a great starting point... The most what I learned until now was from tutorials and some sample code. I found this answer to [Model Data:] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179236/how-to-deal-with-model-classes-in-ios-application). There is also a [sample code.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1232650/linked/stackoverflow/SimpleModel.zip).Is it what you mean? Don´t you know some website, which explain me more deeply Models to store selections? Would it be possible to modify my code to see how it functions? Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: The sample code you provided in the above comment works like native Contacts app. You have a list of contacts and when you click on 1, details of that person are displayed.

Comment: From what I understand from your question is I think you are trying to do something like a Settings page, you configure some settings and that is applicable to entire app. If you don't have many options in your MainViewController then you could alternatively use `NSUserDefaults` as well.

Comment: For the kind of `Model` as described in my answer, I think you will need to use a `Singleton class` to access or store values. One of the examples on how to implement `Singleton class`: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: What I want to do is more like a shopping cart. You click on a button Add to a cart and it will send it to the shopping cart in UITableView... I was searching for some tutorials, for some sample code, but I didn´t find something useful.

Comment: I have updated my answer with various options that you could use. I would suggest to check merits and demerits of all the approaches and see which one is suitable to you

Comment: Thank you! I´ll check all options.

Comment: Because of your answer, I found a great tutorial on a Data Model: http://www.hollance.com/2011/04/making-your-classes-talk-to-each-other-part-1/  So thank you very very much for your answer!

Comment: Thanks for that. I have updated that in my answer for future reference