# How to separate CoreData management from the AppDelegate in OSX applications

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, separation-of-concerns, appdelegate

If you are not interested in my story, jump to the two numbered questions on the bottom now.

In [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267520/where-to-place-the-core-data-stack-in-a-cocoa-cocoa-touch-application), it is discussed whether or not to separate the CoreData handling from the AppDelegate. I decided to try the separation of concerns way.

Since Apple does not provide documentation on that topic for AppKit applications, my question is:

- Is there any documentation, resource or even a sample project that shows how to separate the CoreData stack from the AppDelegate?

My current state is this:

I have an `AppDelegate` and a `DataController` which is a subclass of `NSTreeController`. The `DataController` controls a `NSOutlineView` which shows objects (groups and leafs) of my `CoreData` model.

I started with the `CoreData` (not Document based) template from Xcode.

- I moved all CoreData-Stack related methods from the `AppDelegate` to the `DataController`.
- I made the `DataController` a singleton.
- I forwarded the true `AppDelegate` related methods to the `DataController` like so:

In AppController.m

```
- (NSUndoManager *)windowWillReturnUndoManager:(NSWindow *)window{
    return [[[DataController sharedController] managedObjectContext] undoManager];
}
- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender{
    [[DataController sharedController] saveAction:sender];
}
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender{
    return [[DataController sharedController] applicationShouldTerminate:sender];
}
```

- All those called methods were of course implemented in DataController.m

Now I am able to add and remove objects in the `NSOutlineView`, undo and redo also works. However, the File-Save menu item is grayed out, when I hit cmd+s I get the the bing from the OS. (This used to work 'magically' when I had the CoreData stack in AppDelegate.)

When I quit the application my objects in the `OutlineView` are written to the `persistentStore` (I saw the xml) through the `applicationShouldTerminate` call. However, when I restart the application, the objects are not restored to the `OutlineView`. (This used to work 'magically' when I had the CoreData stack in AppDelegate.)

1. What magic glue code, that is hidden in the `CoreData` template makes cmd+s work and enables the File - Save menu item?
2. What hidden code restores the content of my `mangedObjectContext` to my `OutlineView` on application launch.

Comment: I've only done this for iOS so it's not exactly what you're looking for but the implementation I use is based on http://nachbaur.com/blog/smarter-core-data

Comment: You need to have the file save action in the responder chain, so you could either add a controller to the responder chain or consider implementing it in the app delegate - which is in the responder chain by default.

Comment: @Monolo Thanks for mentioning `responder chain`! I connected (using right click) the `First Responder`s saveAction to the Save... menu item. Since I'm already forwarding the saveAction of the `AppDelegate` to the `DataController`, the menu item was enabled and cmd+s works too.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a framework for iOS that does this.  My approach takes the Core Data boilerplate code from the AppDelegate and moves it into a singleton class.  This gives a clean separation from the AppDelegate, removes the need to pass a `NSManagedObjectContext` among view controllers, and lets you add Core Data into an application by just copying the framework into your project.

You can read about the framework at http://schwiiz.org/?p=1120 or download it from https://github.com/chriscdn/RHManagedObject.

The framework is more than just a singleton.  It also extends `NSManagedObject` to simplify things like saving among different threads and fetching.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link. I had a look at your project and it looks very solid. However, I guess the issues I have are really platform dependent.